# An unspecified error occurred on the render thread. (NotifyPartitionIsZombie)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, render

OK here's the problem,
I have a ContentControl3D object from [thriple](http://thriple.codeplex.com/)
in that im creating a LibraryStack with images it runs fine, until i run the function where the LibraryStack gets created and filled. when i click on any of the objects inside i get the following error

```
An unspecified error occurred on the render thread.
```

with stacktrace

```
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyPartitionIsZombie(Int32 failureCode)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyChannelMessage()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at WelkoMap.App.Main() in F:\MediaGarde\Surface\Development\WelkoMap\WelkoMap\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

here's the code that adds and creates the LibraryStack and fills it

```
public void ReplaceBackContent(List<Image> images, List<MediaElement> videos)
{
    ContentControl3D control = this.TryFindParent<ContentControl3D>();
    if (control == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    LibraryStack stack = new LibraryStack();

    foreach (Image image in images)
    {
        if (image.Parent != null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        LibraryStackItem item = new LibraryStackItem();
        item.Content = image;
        stack.Items.Add(item);

    }
    control.BackContent = stack;
}
```

Since it has the NotifyPartitionIsZombie error i already installed windows update KB967634 which had absolutely no effect at all

Answer (score 1):

I hate this exception! I'm investigating it too and thought I'd post what I have found.

- Are your graphics cards drivers up to date?
- I'd also use snoop and inspect one of the objects and check for heights, widths or positions that are NAN.
- Ensure [Window.AllowsTransparency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) is false

There is a post on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b2aa4601-3f66-4dd6-8a20-0744265c5f1c/) that claims a WinDbg memory dump can help Microsoft investigate.

I hope something here helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/11/20/10469037.aspx) is a detailed explanation about this error and what you can do about it.

Comment: It seems that your link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the exception still creeps up on some PCs I've noticed.

In addition to making sure your graphics drivers are up to date, it also helped me when I changed hardware acceleration to a minimum level (specifically with Matrox cards).

(On Win7): right-click > personalize > display > change display settings > advanced settings > troubleshoot > change settings

And I agree with David, this is a horrible exception to encounter!